# For-Each an Object in Azure Devops pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, microservices

I starting to write an application in microservices and want to have a build step to push the image from my pipeline. For this at the moment I have 3 services to push:

```
  - stage: build_and_publish_containers
    displayName: 'Docker (:Dev Push)'
    jobs:
      - template: "docker/publish.yaml"
        parameters:
          appName: Authorization_Service
          projectPath: "Services/AuthorizationService"
          imageName: authorization-service
          imageTag: ${{variables.imageTag}}
          
      - template: "docker/publish.yaml"
        parameters:
          appName: Registration_Service
          projectPath: "Services/RegistrationService"
          imageName: registration-service
          imageTag: ${{variables.imageTag}}
          
      - template: "docker/publish.yaml"
        parameters:
          appName: Tenant_Service
          projectPath: "Services/TenantService"
          imageName: tenant-service
          imageTag: ${{variables.imageTag}}
```

Even with only this 3 services (and I want to have much more) I have a lot of duplicated code here I want to reduce.
I tried it with an array and an each-function but I have several information here (name / path / imagename) and that could grow.

Is there a better way?

If that would be a programming language I would have an array of a data model, is that something that is possible in azure devops?

Or maybe could each information saved in a json file (so 3 files at the moment and growing) and azure could get all files and informations out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could check the example below to define your complex object nested loops in Azure pipelines. By the way, you could also look into the [github doc](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/each-expression.md#scenarios) for more reference.

```
parameters:
- name: environmentObjects
  type: object
  default: 
  - environmentName: 'dev'
    result: ['123']
  - environmentName: 'uat'
    result: ['223', '323']

pool:
  vmimage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- ${{ each environmentObject  in parameters.environmentObjects }}: 
  - ${{ each result  in environmentObject.result }}:
    - script: echo ${{ result  }}
```